# Dagger 2 injection returning null

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

So here is my application file

```
private AppComponent component;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setupGraph();
}

private void setupGraph() {
    component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
    component.inject(this);
}

public AppComponent component() {
    return component;
}
```

App component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = {
        AppModule.class
    }
)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(BaseActivity activity);

    void inject(BaseFragment fragment);
}
```

ActivityModule:

```
@Module public final class ActivityModule {

private final Activity activity;

public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Provides @ActivityContext
public Context provideActivityContext() {
    return activity;
}

/**
 * Expose the activity to dependents in the graph.
 */
@Provides @PerActivity
Activity activity() {
    return this.activity;
}

@Provides @GetFragmentManager
public FragmentManager provideFragmentManager() {
    return ((BaseActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

Activity Component:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = {ActivityModule.class, PresenterModule.class})
public interface ActivityComponent {
    //Exposed to sub-graphs.
    Activity activity();
}
```

I'm doing injection in my BaseActivity like this

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).component().inject(this)
```

Not sure if this injection is proper but I get no compilation errors.

Now, Problem comes when I'm trying to access presenter in my fragment because it is null. I'm defining my presenter module as follows

Presenter Module:
1. 1st Try

```
@Module
public class PresenterModule {

    @Provides @PerActivity
    public Presenter accessPresenter(MyPresenter presenter){
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

2. 2nd Try

   @Module
   public class PresenterModule {

   ```
   @Provides @PerActivity
   public Presenter accessPresenter(){
       return new MyPresenter();
   }
   ```

   }

In my fragment I'm doing

```
@Inject MyPresenter presenter;
```

and on my onViewCreated I'm trying to set the view as

```
presenter.setView(this); // This is null
```

MyPresenter is a similar to this [EffectiveAndroidUI](https://github.com/pedrovgs/EffectiveAndroidUI/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/pedrovgs/effectiveandroidui/ui/presenter/TvShowPresenter.java) only difference is I have nothing in my constructor.

Comment: Hope you had added application class name in the Android Manifest file. Without it, the app will work but the dagger component will be null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't injecting your fragment. When you annotate a member with `@Inject`, you have to also call `yourObjectGraph.inject(this)` where the signature of the inject method is as follows:

```
void inject(YourFragmentClass fragment);
```

You have two options for getting your presenter to your fragment. Add this method above to your application component and call it in your onCreate() function. Or just pass your fragment the presenter when you create it.
Ex:

```
YourFragmentClass newInstance(Bundle savedInstance, YourPresenter presenter) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: I think that's a requirement for Dagger1.. because object graph is deprecated in dagger 2.

Comment: Not exactly, you call the `inject(...)` method that you define in your component interface to fulfill dependencies. It is essentially creating an object graph. The only difference is that you define the inject method in Dagger 2, whereas it is already defined in dagger 1. Just add the inject method to your application component and you will be able to call `inject(...)` on your fragment.

Comment: Won't the baseFragment will fulfill this requirement.

Right now I'm injecting my BaseFragment same as like my baseActivity
((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getApplicationComponent().inject(this);

Comment: When you call `inject(...)` on a class, Dagger can only inject members of the class itself and its super class(es). Dagger has no idea about the members you want to inject in your derived classes because neither does your base class.

Comment: Interesting..Thanks this works.. but is there any better way to do it..like I just inject my base class and it can inject my derived class as well.

Comment: It depends. If your derived classes don't need any extra dependancies than your base classes then you are fine. Your other option is just passing in the dependancies you need when you construct the object. That is probably the ideal approach because then there is no need for dagger on your fragment level; in other words, less code.

Answer (score 0):

You need reference your presenter like an Interface:

```
@ActivityScope @Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
modules = { GenreModule.class })
public interface GenreFragmentComponent {
  void inject(GenreFragment genreFragment);
  GenrePresenter getPresenter(); // Like this
}
```

The complete sample here: https://github.com/ppamorim/Amazing-MVP

Comment: Why is that necessary to have presenter as an interface?

Comment: Presenter isn't as an interface, this is an "reference" of the presenter.

Otherwise:
Dagger 1 is a little bit complicated to understand. I recommend you to start at Dagger 2.
No reflections, a simple pre processor. A lot of benefits.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I injected a class to a fragment instead of it's presenter, then corrected it.